# Value Assignment in C

Tags: c

I came across this question and expected it to show up as a compile time error but to my surprise each statement separated by comma is executed and the final value is assigned to the variable.

```
int a,b=5;
a=(b++,++b,b*4,b-3);
printf("%d",a);

Output is 4
```

This output is exactly what should be the printed when each of those comma separated statements are executed separately. What I am not understanding is how and why does C allow this and how does compiler process this.

Comment: What do you mean how?

Comment: Look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator It's an operator not often used because it can lead to confusing code. The for loop is the most common place where you can find it.

Comment: the "how" is as in how does the compiler process this, what are the brackets ( ) actually doing here

Comment: thanks a lot @A.R.C. it all makes sense now. It was my first time seeing this syntax outside of a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do)

After understanding how the comma operator works, we can tell that this code is equivalent to:

```
int a,b=5;
b++;
++b;
b*4; // nonsense, the result isn't stored anywhere
a=b-3;
printf("%d",a);
```

5 + 1 + 1 - 3 = 4. The `b*4` part does nothing and is just obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

**comma** acts both as a separator (in declaration of variables) and operator (evaluation of expressions).

In this case, comma acts as an operator. The comma operator introduces a sequence point between expressions.

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

So your code is:

```
a = (b++, ++b, b*4, b-3);
```

Which is as if you had written this:

```
a = (5, 7, 28, 4);
```

So `a` is 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining both the usages. I was missing this and was having a really hard time trying to figure out what was happening.